# Computing integral partial

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Can anyone help me with the following exercise.

Let $Y \sim N(0,1)$. I want to compute $P(|Y|\geq y)$ by integration by parts.
$P(|Y| \geq y)=P(-y \leq Y \leq y)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-y}^{y} x e^{-0.5x^2}dx$ but now I don't know how to choose $u$ and $v$ to end up with $\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\dfrac{e^{-y^2/2}}{y}-\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}\int_{y}^{\infty} y^{-2}e^{\dfrac{-y^2}{2}}$

I have tried $u=x e^{0.5x^2}$,$v'=1$ and $u=e^{-0.5 x^2}$ and $v'=x$, but that doesn't work.
Can anyone help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: The integral that you wrote is  $\mathbb{E}Y $ and not $P(|Y|>y)$, moreover $P(|Y|>y) = P(Y>y, Y<-y) =  2P(Y>y)$.

Comment: Ah okay I see! But ok then I want to compute $2(1-P(Y \leq y)=2[1-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{z} e^{\dfrac{-x^2}{2}}$], but now I have the same problem.

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Answer (score -1):

Let $I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-y}^{y} x e^{-0.5x^2}\,dx$

Let $u = \frac{-x^2}{2}$. Then $u'=-x$

So: $I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-y}^{y} -e^{u}\,\frac{du}{dx}dx$

$I = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-y}^{y} e^{u}\,du$

Comment: In fact, $\Big(e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}\Big)^{'}=-xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ so no need to come up with substitution.

Comment: Yes - I guess it's just my personal preference to use substitution rather than recognition. If I'm not mistaken, your comment above invalidates my answer? Or will the same maths be applied?

Comment: Moreover you can notice that $f(x) = f(-x)$, where $f(x) =xe^{\frac{x^2}{2}} $, so integral is 0, since interval is symmetric. Maybe OP is just interested in computing this integral and doesn't care about anything else :)